# Compute the exterior product of $n$ copies of $\omega=dx_1 \wedge dx_2+\cdots+dx_{2n-1}\wedge dx_{2n}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, manifolds, differential-forms

> Let $\omega$ be the $2$-form in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ given by 
>   $$\omega=dx_1 \wedge dx_2+dx_3\wedge dx_4+\cdots dx_{2n-1}\wedge
>  dx_{2n}$$ Compute the exterior product of $n$ copies of $\omega$.
>
> (Chapter 1, Exercise 7 in Differential Forms and Applications by Manfredo P. do Carmo)

The wording of the problem is kind of difficult for me to understand, but I suppose that the exercise asks us to calculate $\omega \wedge \cdots \wedge \omega$.

So, I think the only way one can get a non-zero coefficient is that if we permute the parentheses $(dx_1 \wedge dx_2)$ up to $(dx_{2n-1}\wedge dx_{2n})$. There are $n!$ such permutations. Since each permutation can be arranged to $dx_1\wedge dx_2 \wedge dx_3 \wedge dx_4 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{2n-1}\wedge dx_{2n}$ with an even number of transpositions, we always get $+1$ as the coefficient of the differential form. So, the answer should be

$$\omega\wedge\cdots\wedge\omega=\color{green}{n!}\,dx_1\wedge dx_2 \wedge dx_3\wedge dx_4 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{2n-1}\wedge dx_{2n}$$

Is that right? If I write my argument exactly like here, would it be considered a complete calculation and receive full points in an exam of differential manifolds?

Comment: It is correct, except for the missing argument showing that all of these permutations are equal to $dx_1 \wedge dx_2 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{2n}$ with a plus sign. Can you add that in?

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thanks for taking the time to read it. Doesn't saying that all of them can be rearranged to $dx_1 \wedge dx_2 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{2n}$ with an even number of transpositions suffice?

Comment: Yeah, but why is the number of transpositions even?

Comment: @darijgrinberg Because if I want to move $dx_1$ to the first position, I will have to jump over, let's say $2m$, elements (i.e. $2m$ transpositions), then if I want to do the same to $dx_2$, again I have to jump over some even number of elements. I know that it's kind of a handwavy argument, but it's right. Right? can I say it in a less handwavy way?

Comment: Yep, there is a less handwavy way. Note that any element of the form $dx_i \wedge dx_j$ commutes with any form (even or odd). Thus, the $n$ parentheses you are sorting into order all commute with each other.

Comment: You can say that for every $dx_k$ that is out of place comes with another that is out of place; either $dx_{k-1}$ or $dx_{k+1}$ depending on whether $k$ is even or odd. Therefore the parity of the permutation is the parity of the permutation of the numbers $2,4,6,...,2n$ times $2$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg In other words, you're using the fact that $\varphi \wedge \omega = (-1)^{ks} \omega \wedge \varphi$ where $\omega$ is a $k$-form and $\varphi$ is an $s$-form. Right? Isn't the proof of this fact itself kind of handwavy? xD

Comment: @logarithm Yes, I agree with you. But that's also kind of a handwavy argument in my opinion. Of course your argument is correct and there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @stressedout: That proof can be done slickly by inducting on $k$ and then on $s$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Yes, I agree with you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is correct, except for the fact that you need to justify why each of your permuted pairs of $dx_{i}\wedge dx_{i+1}$ when wedged together form $dx_1\wedge\cdots\wedge dx_{2n}$ without a sign. This is because: given forms $\alpha,\beta$ of degrees $k,\ell$ respectively,
$$\alpha\wedge\beta=(-1)^{k\ell} \beta\wedge \alpha. $$
In particular, here $\deg(\alpha)=\deg(\beta)=2$ so that 
$$ (dx_{i}\wedge dx_{i+1})\wedge (dx_j\wedge dx_{j+1})=(-1)^4 (dx_j\wedge dx_{j+1})\wedge (dx_i\wedge dx_{i+1})=(dx_j\wedge dx_{j+1})\wedge (dx_i\wedge dx_{i+1})$$
for any choice of $i\ne j$ (both even).

Comment: Yup. Thank you.